# Trying to recall a theorem about metabelian groups with a surprisingly simple proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to recall a theorem I saw once about metabelian groups -- it was either of the form "Every metabelian group satisfies..." or of the form "Every group satisfying ... is metabelian".

What was significant/surprising about it was that even though the problem had been open for a while, the proof ultimately just consisted of a few lines of algebraic manipulations (an exception to Scott Aaaronson's [number 6](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=304)).

Unfortunately that's all I remember.  Does anyone have any idea what I might be referring to? Thanks!

**Edit:** It may have been showing that semidirect products of a certain form are metabelian?  Not sure.  (Now that we have the answer, it wasn't, though this was close.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a really vague question, and who knows what you saw when, except maybe you, (and you apparently don't).  However, one theorem which might fit the bill (it's a nice theorem and it does no harm to publicise it) is that if $G = AB$ for Abelian subgroups $A$ and $B$, not necessarily normal, then the derived group $G^{\prime}$ is Abelian, so $G$ is metabelian. This is a theorem of N.Ito, the proof is a couple of lines, and it had been an open problem for a while.

Noboru Itô, *[Über das Produkt von zwei abelschen Gruppen](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01180647)*, Math. Z. **62**(1) (1955), 400-401, [MR71426](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=71426).

Comment: Would it be possible to insert the proof?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves: you can see the first page when clicking on the link in the answer.

Comment: Alternative links: [link 1](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/en/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN266833020_0062&DMDID=dmdlog32) --- [link 2](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/en/dms/img/?PPN=PPN266833020_0062&DMDID=dmdlog32).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is it. Thank you!